# Laravel 5.2 relationships: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: laravel-5

I have two models: Term and Post.

The Term model represents both categories and tags.
A post can belong only to a category and it can have many tags (I use the same db table for categories and tags).

```
class Term extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'mydb_terms';

    public $timestamps = true;

    public function getRouteKeyName() {
       return 'slug';
    }

    public function posts(){
       return $this -> hasMany('Post');
    }
}


class Post extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'mydb_posts';

    public $timestamps = true;


    public function category(){
       return $this -> belongsTo('Term','mydb_posts_terms', 'post_id', 'term_id') 
          -> withPivot('order') -> withTimestamps() -> where('type','category');
    }

    public function tags(){
       return $this -> hasMany('Term') -> where('type','tag');
    }
}
```

In the CategoryController I have:

```
 class CategoryController extends Controller
 {


      public function getPostsOfCategory($id)
      {
          $posts = Term::find($id)->posts->get();
      }


      public function getPostsOfAllCategories()
      {
          //
      }
 }
```

When I try to retrieve the posts of category `event` with slug `event` (in the db the category and one post in it exist, and also the corresponding row in `mydb_posts_terms`) I obtain

```
 Trying to get property of non-object
```

**EDIT**

I tried both `$posts = Term::find($id)->posts()->get();` by obtaining `Call to a member function` and `$posts = Term::find($id)->posts;` by obtaining the same `Trying to get property of non-object`.

In the db I have:

Table `mydb_terms`:

```
| id | name  | slug  |   type   | created_at         | updated_at
| 1  | event | event | category | 2016-07-01 18:00:00| 2016-07-01 18:00:00
```

Table `mydb_posts`:

```
| id | title   | content   | created_at         | updated_at
| 1  | A title | a content | 2016-07-04 17:20:12| 2016-07-04 17:20:12
```

Table `mydb_posts_terms`:

```
| post_id | term_id   | order   | created_at         | updated_at
| 1       |   1       |   0     | 2016-07-06 14:13:43| 2016-07-06 14:13:43
```

Comment: It's not `->posts->get()`, it's `->posts()->get()` or `posts;`

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu: with ->posts()->get(); I obtain `Call to a member function posts() on a non-object`, while with ->posts; the same `Trying to get property of non-object`.

Comment: That means the `Term::find($id)` is not returning anything, so you can never get to the `posts()` method. Try to `dd(Term::find($id)` to see the result and consider moving to `Term::findOrFail($id)`

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu: dd(Term::find($id)) returns `null`, but I don't know where is the problem. The db values seems ok (I edited the question)

Comment: What about `dd($id)`?

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu: It prints `"event"`

Comment: Methods `find` or similar always uses Primary Key (id) as a lookup. You should be using `Term::where('name', $id)->first();` instead. Also, consider renaming the variable to `$name` instead of `$id`. At the end, you'll have something like `Term::where('name', $name)->first()->posts;`

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu: I thought that by using `public function getRouteKeyName() {
       return 'slug';
    }` did the magic. However `Term::where('slug', $slug)->posts;` (I renamed the variable) returns `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$posts`

Comment: you forgot `->get()` at `Term::where('slug', $slug)->get()->posts;`

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu: quite the same `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$posts`

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad, it's `first()` and not `get()`. My early comment was better written: `Term::where('name', $name)->first()->posts;`

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'mydb_posts.term_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `mydb_posts` where `mydb_posts`.`term_id` = 1 and `mydb_posts`.`term_id` is not null and `mydb_posts`.`deleted_at` is null)` It searches for `term_id`

Comment: Your `my_db_posts` don't have a `term_id`. What you want is actually a `return hasManyThrough('Post', 'PostsTerms');` (by creating a new model for `mydb_posts_term`). That way, you can return many `Posts` through a intermediate class `PostsTerms`.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu: but `mydb_posts_terms` is a pivot table, isn't it? I have to see again the Eloquent relationships. Thanks.